# Extracting a subset of Sequences from fastq files using set() and FastqGeneralIterator()

Tags: python, parsing, for-loop, conditional-statements, biopython

I have two fastq files and I only need the shared fastq records. However my script fails when writing two different files only containing the matching records. I am using set() to for optimized memory use. can someone help me fix the problem? here is the code:

```
from Bio.SeqIO.QualityIO import FastqGeneralIterator

infileR1= open('R1.fastq', 'r')
infileR2= open('R2.fastq', 'r')
output1= open('matchedR1.fastq', 'w')
output2= open('matchedR2.fastq', 'w')

all_names1 = set()
for line in infileR1 :
    if line[0:11] == '@GWZHISEQ01':
        read_name = line.split()[0]
        all_names1.add(read_name)

all_names2 = set()
for line in infileR2 :
    if line[0:11] == '@GWZHISEQ01':
        read_name = line.split()[0]
        all_names2.add(read_name)

shared_names = set()
for item in all_names1:
    if item in all_names2:
        shared_names.add(item)

#printing out the files:

for title, seq, qual in FastqGeneralIterator(infileR1):
    if title in new:
        output1.write("%s\n%s\n+\n%s\n" % (title, seq, qual))

for title, seq, qual in FastqGeneralIterator(infileR2):
    if title in shared_names:
        output2.write("%s\n%s\n+\n%s\n" % (title, seq, qual))

infileR1.close() 
infileR2.close()
output1.close()
output2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact error (you should add a description of it instead of saying just "it fails"), I guess you are re-using a handler that is exhausted.

- You open a handler with `infileR1= open('R1.fastq', 'r')`
- Then you read the file with `for line in infileR1:` to get the headers.
- Finally you pass the same handler to `FastqGeneralIterator`, but the pointer is at the end of the file, so the Iterator is already at the end of the file and yields nothing.

You should either "rewind" the file with `infileR1.seek(0)` before the last loops or change your code to use the `SeqIO` wrapper as recommended in the docs passing the file name:

```
infileR1.close()

for record in SeqIO.parse("R1.fastq", "fastq"):
    # Do business here
```